# trying to understand late static bindings in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
class Record {

    protected static $tableName = 'base';

    public static function getTableName() {
        echo self::$tableName;
    }
}
class User extends Record {
    protected static $tableName = 'users';
}
User::getTableName();
```

It shows: base

Question:

I know I can change the problem by changing this line `echo self::$tableName;` to `echo static::$tableName;`, it is called 'late static bindings', I read the doc [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php), but still not quite understand it. So could you give me some explanation on:

a. why this line of code `echo self::$tableName;` shows: base?

b. why this line of code `echo static::$tableName;` shows: users?

Comment: This is only a guess, but `static::` probably resolves the actual type of the object, rather than the compile-time known type, and looks for a static variable named `$tableName` on that type.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`self` is "bound" at compile time, statically. That means when the code is *compiled*, it is decided what `self` refers to. `static` is resolved at *run time*, i.e. when the code is executed. That's *late* static binding. And that's the difference.

With `self`, it is decided at compile time (when the code is "read"), that `self` refers to `Record`. Later on the code for `User` is parsed, but `self::$tableName` in `Record` already refers to `Record::$tableName` and cannot be changed anymore.

When you use `static`, the reference is not resolved immediately. It is only resolved when you call `User::getTableName()`, at which point you're in the context of `User`, so `static::$tableName` is resolved to `User::$tableName`.

In other words: `self` always refers to the class that it has been written in, no two ways about it. What `static` refers to depends on what context it's used in; in practice that means it may refer to child classes if the class it occurs in is being extended. That makes it work like `$this`, only for static contexts.

Comment: +1 "like $this, only for static contexts". That is probably the most eloquently I've heard the behavior described

Comment: Official PHP docs-team should hire you! Or help them yourself voluntarily ;-)

Answer (score 4):

`self` references the defining class scope.

`static` references calling classes scope.

`self::$tableName` references the class where it was defined. ie Record

`static::$tableName` references the class that it was invoked upon. ie User

Answer (score 2):

The example below will give a minimum example of late static binding:

```
class A {
    static public $name = "A";

    static public function getName () {
        return self::$name;
    }

    static public function getNameLateStaticBinding () {
        return static::$name;
    }
}


class B extends A {
    static public $name = "B";
}



// Output: A
echo A::getName(), "\n";

// Output: A
echo B::getName(), "\n";

// Output: B
echo B::getNameLateStaticBinding() , "\n";
```

`B::getName()` outputs the `$name` variable from `A` since `self` is computed from the absolute current class you defined `self` in. To solve such cases, use `static`.

Answer (score -1):

suggest you read about 'Object Inheritance' http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php